# Loading Background Image to Custom Html page in Web browser control

Tags: html, wpf-controls, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a scenario where I would need to navigate to my own custom html page, when the any request fails. The issue I am facing is I have a background Image which I need to display with the custom html page.

I have implemented the code as follows:

```
CustomHtmlDoc = "<html><head></head><body background=\"{0}\"; oncontextmenu='return false;'><br><br></br></br><hr><h4 style='font-family:Footlight MT Light;color:red;font-size:20px;'>" + "ErrorMessage" + "</h4><h4 style='font-family:Footlight MT Light;color:red;font-size:25px;'>Please Verify the Configured URL from Dashboard Configuration</h4> <hr></body></html>";
string CustomHtmlDocument = string.Format(CustomHtmlDoc,AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "AdministrationUIBrowser\\AdministrationUIBrowserFactory\\ErrorBackground.png");
WebBrowserControlView.DocumentText = CustomHtmlDocument;
```

I am able to get the error page as background when I try to run the scenario locally. But at the deployed end, I am just getting blank screen with only content without any background Image. Mine is a WPF application.

Comment: What is the actual `CustomHtmlDocument` content for case when it doesn't work. E.g., this works:    `this.webBrowser.DocumentText = @"<b>This is an image:</b> <img src='file://C:\Users\User\Downloads\pic.png'>"`. What you got?

Comment: CustomHtmlDoc = @"<html><head></head><body background=\"{0}\"; oncontextmenu='return false;'><br><br></br></br><hr><h4 style='font-family:Footlight MT Light;color:red;font-size:20px;'>" + "ErrorMessage" + "</h4><h4 style='font-family:Footlight MT Light;color:red;font-size:25px;'>Please Verify the Configured URL from Dashboard Configuration</h4> <hr></body></html>";     When setting absolute url path as you mention "c:\users\.....\pic.png" it is displaying correct. But In the deployed server, the background is not displayed

Comment: You should have edited your question (not comments) to show the code. Anyway, what's the absolute URL when it's deployed? Is it reachable?

Comment: I am not able to reach the absolute location in deployed server, seems the image is as a resource in the dll.

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentText implementation in Windows Forms does not implement IMoniker and the loaded document will have a base address of about:blank, thus your page cannot find the background image.

You can use a base element to specify the base location for relative urls, or implement a url moniker. There is a sample on implementing a url moniker at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx. Search LoadHtmlIntoBrowser(string html, string sBaseUrl) on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Base64 encoded image. [Check this service out](http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/image-to-base64/). i've tested it and it works like a charm.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try 100% sure
(Image current folder)

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = 
    @"<b>This is an image:</b> <img src='" + 
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) 
    +"/ErrorBackground.png'>";
```